# Default value not selected in the select box

Tags: html, css, select

I am trying to generate a select box from a PHP file as:

```
<select class="form-control no-range-feature-val video-codec-list hidden">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

The option with the value `none` should be selected by default, but it is not. Instead, I get a select box where I have to manually select the `Select` option.

[image]

What could be the reason for it? I have checked in Chrome, Firefox, Edge. They all report the same behavior.

**CSS:**

```css
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

add-feature-field-row .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: add the word selected on that one option

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos Tried but doesn't work.

Comment: <option value="none" selected>Select</option> did you do it like this ? @SuhailGupta

Comment: check , you have a js file  to style this select box , read this documentation

Comment: @HasiburRahaman Yes, bootstrap does it.

Comment: you add the `hidden` class so the result ends up like that try removing it , seel this https://jsfiddle.net/g6e6bjf7/5/

Comment: @ImmortalDude Tried. The same result.

Comment: checked the dom structure rendered by the browser using developer tools??

Answer (score 1):

this works on jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g6e6bjf7/ please show your css as that might cause the issue

```
<select class="form-control no-range-feature-val video-codec-list hidden">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Shared CSS in the question.

Comment: Suhail it seems to work in jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g6e6bjf7/1/ what does the hidden class do?

Comment: It evaluates to `display: none!important;`

Comment: Suhail that is your problem I just added that and it won't work https://jsfiddle.net/g6e6bjf7/2/

Comment: No. That class is not the reason. How could it be? Try to make it visible using javascript and it shall work.

Comment: only other option I can think of is the select gets a color of white or transparent from somewhere, have you checked the page source and does the select option value display there?

Comment: It doesn't get transparent either. The first entry is blank. When I click the select box, `Select` is the first option visible.

Comment: can you post that source please so I can check, this is very strange

Answer (score 0):

try to this..

```
<select class="form-control no-range-feature-val video-codec-list hidden">
            <option value="none" selected>Select</option>
            <option value="1">Select1</option>
     </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select class="form-control no-range-feature-val video-codec-list">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works! But I didn't understand the logic behind/

Comment: check your css , this may make problem , everything is fine with the html code

Comment: @SuhailGupta: The `hidden` class has been removed. Are you sure that's not source of the problem?